# Показ картинки при вводе слова

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Необходима Ваша помощь по реализации следующего:

При вводе определенного текста, к примеру **"apple"** в текстовой строке загружалась/появлялась картинка яблоки.
Вот мой html:

```
<input type="text" onchange="showMe(value)">
<div class = 'div1'></div>
```

Не знаю как реализовать функцию `showMe(value)` на js.

Саму задачу желательно реализовать на **Macromedia Flash Professional**. 
Но можно и на **Javascript**

Comment: это вам на fl.ru

Comment: Времени нет для ожидания. :(

Comment: ну так по щелчку точно ничего не будет)

Comment: А вы случайно не работаете на macromedia?

Comment: не, я на js пишу

Comment: Ну хотя бы на js это не покажете как делается?)

Comment: что конкретно нужно? Загружается обычная страница в браузере и предлагает ввести(к примеру) Яблоко, если я ввожу и нажимаю ОК, то на странице появляется картинка яблок?

Comment: Ну вот допустим есть несколько картинок, допустим яблоки, мандарины и груши. И есть одна тестовая строка, в нем если ввести слово яблоко то картинка яблоки автоматически всплывалась (если трудно можно без анимации) короче говоря показывалась. Без всяких нажатий, просто при вводе "яблока" в строке. Очень Вас прошу помочь, можем обсудить это в ICQ если что.

Comment: Вот так: в правом углу картинки например яблоки, груши и т.д... Внизу текстовое поле и если в нем ввести яблоко и показать то яблоко анимированно показывалась то есть приползла к середину что-ли. Как-то так.

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich переоткрыл вопрос, оформите ответ плз

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" onchange="showMe(value)">
  <div class='div1'></div>
  <script>
    function showMe(value) {
      this.value = value;
      let div = document.querySelector('.div1');
      if ((this.value === 'Яблоки') || (this.value === 'яблоки') || (this.value === 'apple`s') || (this.value === 'Apple`s')) {
        div.innerHTML = '';
        div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', '<img src = "http://findfood.ru/attaches/product/fructi/yabloko.jpg">');
      } else if ((this.value === 'Груши') || (this.value === 'груши') || (this.value === 'Pears') || (this.value === 'pears')) {
        div.innerHTML = '';
        div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', '<img src = "http://chem-polezno.com/img/728xNxgrusha.jpg.pagespeed.ic.wiMtB_xELs.jpg">');
      } else if ((this.value === 'Мандарины') || (this.value === 'мандарины') || (this.value === 'Mandarins')|| (this.value === 'mandarins')) {
        div.innerHTML = '';
        div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', '<img src = "http://polza-vred.su/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B1-300x172.jpg">');
      } else {
        div.innerHTML = '';
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Соответствующие картинки появляются только при вводе определенных слов(например Яблоки или яблоки). Все лишние слова просто игнорируются

Comment: Fuck the system: `гРуши`.